# java object streams

Tags: java, sockets, dataoutputstream

I'm trying to create a server in java which will maintain up to 4 connections simultaneously.  I thought that holding the relevant information in an array would serve my purpose, well, but I'm having some trouble.

Here is the class I've created:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class tcpConnects{
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private int player;
public tcpConnects(int playerNumber, Socket connect) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            System.out.println("create InputStream");
            input= new ObjectInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("create OutputStream");
            output= new ObjectOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("streams created");
            //sendData("Welcome!");
            player=playerNumber;
        }catch (IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public ObjectInputStream getInput(){
        return input;
    }
    public void setInput(ObjectInputStream in){
        input=in;
    }
    public ObjectOutputStream getOutput(){
        return output;
    }
    public void setOutput(ObjectOutputStream out){
        output=out;
    }
    public int getPlayer(){
        return player;
    }
    public void sendData(String data){
        try{
            output.writeObject(data);
            output.flush();
        }catch (IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

anyway, when I send a socket into the class, it gets to the stage of creating the input stream, but then the stream is never actually created.  The syntax appears to be correct, so I can only assume that there is some form of logic error which I am not aware of.  Any help in deciphering why this class will not create an input or output stream would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* the `ObjectInputStream`, at both ends. The constructor of `ObjectOutputStream` writes a header to the stream that the constructor of `ObjectInputStream` reads, so if you create the `ObjectInputStreams` first you get a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks, EJP, you've been a great help!  Creating the output stream first on both ends worked perfectly!